# Whose fault is it? CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint-2010

The slider should function nice and smooth. Instead the animation isn't working smoothly. Here are the HTML, CSS and Javascript.  I looked and looked and looked and can't find the clue. Rotating is not smooth, caption does not match the image, the last image doesn't even appear.   (Here is the [actual demo](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-slider)).
  Here are some sample images showing a bit of the problem:

[image]

[image]

```
<IMG ID="slideshowPicturePlaceholder" src="/_layouts/images/GEARS_AN.GIF" style="display:none"/>

<div id="slideshowContentArea" style="display:none; width:255px;"> 
    <div class="main_view">
        <div class="window">
            <div class="image_reel"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paging">
            <a href="#" rel="1">1</a>
            <a href="#" rel="2">2</a>
            <a href="#" rel="3">3</a>
            <a href="#" rel="4">4</a>
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>

<style type="text/css">
/*--Main Container--*/
.main_view {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
/*--Window/Masking Styles--*/
.window {
    height: 286px;  width: 790px;
    overflow: hidden; /*--Hides anything outside of the set width/height--*/
    position: relative;
}
.image_reel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
.image_reel img {float: left;}

/*--Paging Styles--*/
.paging {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px; right: -7px;
    width: 178px; height:47px;
    z-index: 100; /*--Assures the paging stays on the top layer--*/
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: url(paging_bg2.png) no-repeat;
    display: none; /*--Hidden by default, will be later shown with jQuery--*/
}
.paging a {
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.paging a.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #920000;
    border: 1px solid #610000;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.paging a:hover {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    function GetAllImages()
    {
       $("#slideshowPicturePlaceholder").css("display", "block");
       var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
       soapEnv += "<listName>NewsRotator</listName>";
       soapEnv += "<query><Query><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
       soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/><FieldRef Name='NewsLink'/><FieldRef Name='Description'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";
       soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       var webservice = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

       $.ajax(
       {
          url : webservice,
          type : "POST",
          dataType : "xml",
          data : soapEnv,
          complete : processQueryResults,
          contentType : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          error : function (xhr)
          {
             alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
          }
       });   
    }


    function processQueryResults(xData, status)
    {
       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       // Change the below to point to your image library
       var imageURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/";
       var itemURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=";

       // $("#slideshowContentArea").html("")
       $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function ()
       {
          var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
          var headlines = $(this).attr("ows_Description");
          var imageLink = imageURL + $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").substring($(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").indexOf('#') + 1);
          // // var itemLink = itemURL + $(this).attr("ows_ID");
          var itemLink = $(this).attr("ows_NewsLink");
          //var liHtml = "<div><a href='" + itemLink + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + imageLink + "'/></a></div>";
          //var liHtml ="<a target='_blank' border='0' href='"+itemLink+"'><img src='"+ imageLink +"'/></a>";
          var liHtml = "<a href='"+itemLink+"' target='_blank' border='0'><img src='" + imageLink +"'/></a><p>"+ title + " - " + headlines + "</p>";
          $(".image_reel").append(liHtml);



        });

        $("#slideshowPicturePlaceholder").css("display", "none"); 

        $("#slideshowContentArea").css("display", "block");



         // Show the paging and activate its first link
          $(".paging").show();
          $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

          // Get size of the image, how many images there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
          var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
          var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
          var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

          // Adjust the image reel to its new size
          $(".image_reel").css(
          {
             'width' : imageReelWidth
          }
          );



        // Paging  and Slider Function
        rotate = function ()
        {
           var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1;
           // Get number of times to slide
           var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth;
           // Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

           $(".paging a").removeClass('active');
           // Remove all active class
           $active.addClass('active');
           // Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

           // Slider Animation
           $(".image_reel").animate(
           {
              left : - image_reelPosition
           }
           , 500);

        }
        ;

        // Rotation  and Timing Event
        rotateSwitch = function ()
        {
           play = setInterval(function ()
           {
              // Set timer - this will repeat itself every 7 seconds
              $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
              // Move to the next paging
              if ($active.length === 0)
              {
                 // If paging reaches the end...
                 $active = $('.paging a:first');
                 // go back to first
              }
              rotate();
              // Trigger the paging and slider function
           }
           , 3000);
           // Timer speed in milliseconds (7 seconds)
        }
        ;

        rotateSwitch();
        // Run function on launch

        // On Hover
        $(".image_reel a").hover(function ()
        {
           clearInterval(play);
           // Stop the rotation
        }
        , function ()
        {
           rotateSwitch();
           // Resume rotation timer
        }        );

        // On Click
        $(".paging a").click(function ()
        {
           $active = $(this);
           // Activate the clicked paging
           // Reset Timer
           clearInterval(play);
           // Stop the rotation
           rotate();
           // Trigger rotation immediately
           rotateSwitch();
           // Resume rotation timer
           return false;
           // Prevent browser jump to link anchor
        }
        );


          }


GetAllImages();

});

</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java.

Comment: Yes I think we can definitively rule out Java as a suspect.

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: Nobody wants to read through all this code. It is your project, your problem, so do some research and narrow it down if you want help.

Comment: Stack Overflow allows you to add images, how about you save the image in the Word document and upload into your post.  That way we don't have to sign-up for that service.

Comment: yes sir, it's javascript on client side. Both IE and Firefox having same issues.

Comment: Your first link is missing, probably because the site wouldn't let you post more than one link.  Leave it in a comment here and I'll add it.

Comment: Fault is always the Coder , and its  You :-)

Comment: Thank you Lance for letting me post the word. Here is the link http://www.easy-share.com/1915763307/image%20rotator%20issues.docx. or I can email it to you. I tried to upload pics but as a new user i havnt earned the privilege to add images.

Comment: @Zod: lol. like the humor. I am sure it's me. I am confessing. Just need another pair of eyes to guide me. Thanks Zod

Comment: @Chrislegend: I totally agree with you. I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything. I went to through IE dev tool and firebug but apparently they don't throw any error.

Comment: @zod, that's not true, there are bugs in languages.

Comment: @Danny, I meant the first link, the second is already there, but I don't want to sign up for their service.  You can use something like http://imageshack.us/, and then use the short links they give you.

Comment: @Lance: Thank you sir. I am uploading them to imageshack. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/683/imagerotator1.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/813/imagerotator2.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/imagerotator3.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/imagerotator4.png/

Comment: I'm not sure which one is the "nice and smooth" ideal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Lance: oh, see demo here http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-slider/

Comment: Works fine in my browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Tyilo: The demo works fine on my browser. But the code i posted not working on my browsers (both ie and firefox)

Comment: @Danny Please don't repost the same question in various forms over and over again. If you have more information to provide, edit the question instead. I've closed the other 3 questions that all built up to this one here.

Comment: The issue still stands. hmm. what are my options?

Comment: I think you change many thing from actual demo if you are not expert in css/html you dont have to change that because when we use any jquery feature css/html/javascript/jquery all are interconnected 1 line missing can generate problem so try to use actual demo

Answer (score 1):

This issue might cause because of using position property in CSS. 
position absolute is not necessary for '.image_reel' class, try with float:left.

Answer (score 1):

Is this question still active? try to remove absolute position from your "image_reel"  class